# Javascript animation not working properly in Safari 14

Tags: javascript, animation, safari

For a portfolio website, I’m using a code snippet I found [here](https://codepen.io/Web_Cifar/pen/JjXrLRJ), a sort of DVD animation. Since I’ve installed Safari 14 on Mac OS Big Sur, the animation is not working properly. It seems that it leaves some marks of its movement. Does someone know this issue? How can I solve it? Thanks a lot.

[Here is a screen cap on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/224sh.gif)
[Here is a screen cap on Safari 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45KXy.gif)

Here is my js for the animation:

```
//Constants
const section = document.getElementById("anim_jtm");
const logo = document.getElementById("logo");
const body = document.getElementById("body");
section.style.height = body.clientHeight + "px";
section.style.width = body.clientWidth + "px";

// Logo moving velocity Variables
let xPosition = 10;
let yPosition = 10;
let xSpeed = 0.7;
let ySpeed = 0.7;

function update() {
  logo.style.left = xPosition + "px";
  logo.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (xPosition + logo.clientWidth >= body.clientWidth || xPosition <= 0) {
    xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    logo.style.fill = randomColor();
  }
  if (yPosition + logo.clientHeight >= body.clientHeight || yPosition <= 0) {
    ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    logo.style.fill = randomColor();
  }

  xPosition += xSpeed;
  yPosition += ySpeed;
  update();
}, 1);

function randomColor() {
  let color = "#";
  color += Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase();

  return color;
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  xPosition = 10;
  yPosition = 10;

  section.style.height = body.clientHeight + "px";
  section.style.width = body.clientWidth + "px";
});
```

Comment: Why not use CSS transforms instead of left/top?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for the help, it seems that CSS translate is working!

Comment: Transform tends to be hardware accelerated and doesn’t cause a browser to recalculate the layout.